# How to test an email confirmation loop

Tags: javascript, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, web-deployment

I want to create an automated test that will do the following for a production environment:
1. Fill out signup form.
2. Wait for and fetch confirmation email (from a gmail account).
3. Open the confirmation link in the email.
4. Delete the account.

So far I have been doing my browser scripting using PhantomJS. But, this won't allow me to use a node module to log in to email.

Is there another tool that will allow for arbitrary code execution (in any language) AND headless browser scripting? Ultimately this script should run in an automated testing environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Selenium Web driver: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

This allows you to completely script everything you want. I know for sure that you can use C# to drive the tests, but if I recall correctly other languages are also supported